# Regex to parse image data URI

Tags: c#, image, base64, uri

If I have :

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhtwBEANUAAMbIypOVmO7v76yusOHi49AsSDY1N2NkZvvs6VVWWPDAutZOWJ+hpPPPyeqmoNlcYXBxdNTV1nx+gN51c4iJjEdHSfbc19M+UOeZk7m7veSMiNtpauGBfu2zrc4RQSMfIP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAC3AEQAAAb/QJBwSCwaj8ikcslsOp/QqHRKrVqv2Kx2y+16v+CweEwum8/otHrNbrvf8Lh8Tq/b7/i8fs" />
```

How can I parse the data part into:

- Mime type (image/gif)
- Encoding (base64)
- Image data (the binary data)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**EDIT**: expanded to show usage

```
var regex = new Regex(@"data:(?<mime>[\w/\-\.]+);(?<encoding>\w+),(?<data>.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var match = regex.Match(input);

var mime = match.Groups["mime"].Value;
var encoding = match.Groups["encoding"].Value;
var data = match.Groups["data"].Value;
```

**NOTE**: The regex applies to the input shown in question. If there was a `charset` specified too, it would not work and would have to be rewritten.

Comment: I tried this but using matches.Groups[0].ToString() in c# it returned everything instead of the mime part. Can you expand the code.

Comment: Here's my code: 
string pattern= @"data:(?<mime>[\w/]+);(?<encoding>\w+),(?<data>.*)";
                       Match matches = Regex.Match(imgsrc, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
                       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br />match: " + matches.Groups[0].ToString());

Comment: I updated the MIME part of the regexp slightly to be able to use with MIME types like application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, where the \w and / is not enough to match (since . and - are not "word" characters).

Comment: Doesn't work for data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,IVRSTlMJVFJ

Comment: I know it's explicit in the question, but I found it was easier to parse without a regular expression by getting the position of the comma and then dealing with the media type/encoding part. The logic was clearer than a complicated regular expression, I could handle cases like @YesMan85 above, and I was getting a bit worried about regex performance for a long data string.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, you don't need a regex for that. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), the data URI format is

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

so just do the following:

```
byte[] imagedata = Convert.FromBase64String(imageSrc.Substring(imageSrc.IndexOf(",") + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I would like to know the mime-type as well so that I can write the data into a file with the right extension, .png if the user submits image/png, .gif if user submits image/gif etc.

Comment: I think this part: imageSrc.IndexOf(",") should be imageSrc.IndexOf(",")-1 to prevent the "," from being included in the data.

Comment: I'd probably use this method to remove the data part, then use Split(';') to get the other parts.  Also, think it should be Indexof(",")+1, not -1.. of course, in real code you would want to check for -1 (not found) result also.

Comment: @Steven you're right, but it's actually `+1` not `-1`.. Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

I faced also with the need to parse the data URI scheme. As a result, I improved the regular expression given on this page specifically for C# and which fits any data URI scheme (to check the scheme, you can take it from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Here is my solution for C#:

```
private class DataUriModel {
  public string MediaType { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string[] Tree { get; set; }
  public string Subtype { get; set; }
  public string Suffix { get; set; }
  public string[] Params { get; set; }
  public string Encoding { get; set; }
  public string Data { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
  string s = "data:image/prs.jpeg+gzip;charset=UTF-8;page=21;page=22;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD";
  var parsedUri = GetDataURI(s);
  Console.WriteLine(decodedUri.Type);
  Console.WriteLine(decodedUri.Subtype);
  Console.WriteLine(decodedUri.Encoding);
}

private static DataUriModel GetDataURI(string data) {
  var result = new DataUriModel();
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\s*data:(?<media_type>(?<type>[a-z\-]+){1}\/(?<tree>([a-z\-]+\.)+)?(?<subtype>[a-z\-]+){1}(?<suffix>\+[a-z]+)?(?<params>(;[a-z\-]+\=[a-z0-9\-\+]+)*)?)?(?<encoding>;base64)?(?<data>,+[a-z0-9\\\!\$\&\'\,\(\)\*\+\,\;\=\-\.\~\:\@\/\?\%\s]*\s*)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
  var match = regex.Match(data);

  if (!match.Success)
    return result;

  var names = regex.GetGroupNames();
  foreach (var name in names) {
    var group = match.Groups[name];
    switch (name) {
      case "media_type": result.MediaType = group.Value; break;
      case "type": result.Type = group.Value; break;
      case "tree": result.Tree = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.Value) && group.Value.Length > 1 ? group.Value[0..^1].Split(".") : null; break;
      case "subtype": result.Subtype = group.Value; break;
      case "suffix": result.Suffix = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.Value) && group.Value.Length > 1 ? group.Value[1..] : null; break;
      case "params": result.Params = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.Value) && group.Value.Length > 1 ? group.Value[1..].Split(";") : null; break;
      case "encoding": result.Encoding = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.Value) && group.Value.Length > 1 ? group.Value[1..] : null; break;
      case "data": result.Data = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.Value) && group.Value.Length > 1 ? group.Value[1..] : null; break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. This was the first time I ran into the C# range operator and since I'm using an older version of C# I had to substitute the uses of the [Range Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemrange) with calls to `Substring()`.  e.g. instead of `group.Value[1..]`, I used `group.Value.Substring(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Data URI's have a bit of complexity to them, they can contain params, media type, etc... and sometimes you need to know this info, not just the data.

To parse a data URI and extract all of the relevant parts, try this:

```js
/**
 * Parse a data uri and return an object with information about the different parts
 * @param {*} data_uri 
 */
function parseDataURI(data_uri) {
    let regex = /^\s*data:(?<media_type>(?<mime_type>[a-z\-]+\/[a-z\-\+]+)(?<params>(;[a-z\-]+\=[a-z\-]+)*))?(?<encoding>;base64)?,(?<data>[a-z0-9\!\$\&\'\,\(\)\*\+\,\;\=\-\.\_\~\:\@\/\?\%\s]*\s*)$/i;
    let result = regex.exec(data_uri);
    let info = {
        media_type: result.groups.media_type,
        mime_type: result.groups.mime_type,
        params: result.groups.params,
        encoding: result.groups.encoding,
        data: result.groups.data
    }
    if(info.params)
        info.params = Object.fromEntries(info.params.split(';').slice(1).map(param => param.split('=')));
    if(info.encoding)
        info.encoding = info.encoding.replace(';','');
    return info;
}
```

This will give you an object that has all the relevant bits parsed out, and the params as a dictionary {foo: baz}.

Example (mocha test with assert):

```js
describe("Parse data URI", () => {
    it("Should extract data URI parts correctly",
        async ()=> {
            let uri = 'data:text/vnd-example+xyz;foo=bar;bar=baz;base64,R0lGODdh';
            let info = parseDataURI(uri);
            assert.equal(info.media_type,'text/vnd-example+xyz;foo=bar;bar=baz');
            assert.equal(info.mime_type,'text/vnd-example+xyz');
            assert.equal(info.encoding, 'base64');
            assert.equal(info.data, 'R0lGODdh');
            assert.equal(info.params.foo, 'bar');
            assert.equal(info.params.bar, 'baz');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: final part of the regex captures trailing whitespace, so your info.data can end with spaces and tabs and such like. Move the final bracket before the *\s* eg: regex = /^\s*data:(?<media_type>(?<mime_type>[a-z\-]+\/[a-z\-\+]+)(?<params>(;[a-z\-]+\=[a-z\-]+)*))?(?<encoding>;base64)?,(?<data>[a-z0-9\!\$\&\'\,\(\)\*\+\,\;\=\-\.\_\~\:\@\/\?\%\s])*\s*$/i;

Answer (score -1):

Here is my regular expression where I had to separate the mime-type (image/jpg) as well.

```
^data:(?<mimeType>(?<mime>\w+)\/(?<extension>\w+));(?<encoding>\w+),(?<data>.*)
```