# Detect data URI in image src using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, base64, html-agility-pack

I process a lot of html and transform it into PDF files. Before I can transform my html I have to detect if any of the images are referenced files. If it is a referenced file then I base64 encode them and replace the src with it.

Right now I am relying on Regex to do the detection for me, but since I am using HtmlAgilityPack I was wondering if I can achieve the same with HtmlAgilityPack?

I would like to do this so I don't have to maintain the Regex when I am currently already using HtmlAgilityPack.

So right now I am detecting the data uri via RegEx with the following:

```
void Main()
{
    var myHtml = @"<html><head></head><body><p><img src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs='/></p></body></html>";
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(myHtml);

    var imgs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
    if (imgs != null && imgs.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var imgNode in imgs)
        {
            var srcAttribute = imgNode.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => string.Equals("src", a.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(srcAttribute?.Value) && !StringIsDataUri(srcAttribute.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BASE ENCODE THE REFERENCED FILE");
            }
        }
    }
}

//Regex from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5714355/1958344
private static Regex regex = new Regex(@"data:(?<mime>[\w/\-\.]+);(?<encoding>\w+),(?<data>.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

private bool StringIsDataUri(string stringToTest)
{
    var match = regex.Match(stringToTest);
    return match.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack doesn't have built-in function to detect data URI, so you still need to incorporate your own implementation of such function.

As an aside, you can use LINQ API of HtmlAgilityPack to select `img` element that have reference `src` attribute in the first place :

```
var referenceImgs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                           .Descendants("img")
                           .Where(o => !StringIsDataUri(o.GetAttributeValue("src","")));

foreach(HtmlNode img in referenceImgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BASE ENCODE THE REFERENCED FILE");
}
```

Comment: Alright that was what I suspected. Thanks for the code update. Your version is way prettier than mine.